# Why can't I download swiglpk and how can I fix it?

Tags: python, package, cmp

[This is the error that i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKZmI.png)

I don't even know what went wrong. I'm new to programming and I need this package (pymIprog) for a college assignement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a `pip install` in a Python 3.9 environment. I can't get that to work either: it fails trying to install `swiglpk`. But it does work in Python 3.8 and Python 3.7.

I can't tell you how to fix it: only the packagers of `swiglpk` can do that. But to get going, you could download Python 3.8, which will coexist nicely with Python 3.9, and work from there.

Python 3.9 only came out quite recently and some packagers take a while to catch up with new releases.

To be sure of running the right version of pip, begin by doing `pip --version` and if it is not the version you expect, run your pip command from `C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried in 3.8 and after setting the correct PATH it worked!

Comment: @SamuelLiew The OP is a beginner and posted the error message as a picture, not knowing any better. But the screenshot is very explicit and simply shows `pip`'s longstanding inability to compile from source on Windows, even with the recommended C compiler installed, something that was finally fixed last October, after four or more years of misery. I found that screenshot sufficiently detailed to answer the question, so I dispute the flag "needs details or clarity".